# Typescript can't find a method defined in a superclass' type definition. What's wrong?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-typings

I'm using JointJS, which comes with typings defined. There, I have a Typescript class defined like so:

```
namespace joint {
    namespace shapes {
        namespace devs {
            class Model extends basic.Generic { ... }
        }
    }
}

namespace basic {
    class Generic extends dia.Element { ... }
}

namespace dia {
    class Element extends Cell { ... }
    class Cell extends Backbone.Model { ... }
}

namespace Backbone {
    class Model extends ModelBase {
    ...
    defaults(): ObjectHash;
}
```

So ultimately, joint.shapes.devs.Model should have that defaults property defined, inherited from `Generic <- dia.Element <- dia.Cell <- Backbone.Model`

However, when I try to extend this object:

```
const extendedModel = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend(
    ...
), joint.shapes.devs.Model.defaults);
```

...typescript says joint.shapes.devs.Model doesn't have this property defined:

`error TS2339: Property 'defaults' does not exist on type 'typeof Model'.`

I tried calling a method instead of just a property:

```
const extendedModel = joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend(
    ...
), joint.shapes.devs.Model.defaults());
```

But I got the same exact message.

I'm on Typescript 2.7.2

My question is: **what is wrong here? How can I fix this?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaults` property exists not on `Model` type, as you are trying to state, but on `Model` instance, i.e. on the object created by `new Model`. Without instance, they just don't make any sense.

Let's look, then, on the definition of `extend()` method:

```
public static extend(properties: any, classProperties?: any): any;
```

So, you're passing this variable as `classProperties`. It seems that this parameter reflects the static properties, i.e. the ones you'll be able to access by `extendedModel.propName`. If you're not planning to use this syntax, you could just leave this argument blank, since it's optional.

Finally, if you're familiar with ES6 classes, it seems to be recommended to use them (by the comment in the definition). In that case, your intention would be expressed just as this:

```
class extendedModel extends joint.shapes.devs.Model {
    // new properties go here
}
```